# How can I avoid usage of multiple throw statement and use only one generic throw statement with required error message

Tags: java

I have a Code which validates the Input String, if Input string, not matches required format I need to throw IllegalArgumentException, there are multiple Fields and Each field has a different set of Validation condition, so for each field currently I am performing "If" check and if That not satisfied I am throwing IllegalArgumentException and there are multiple if condition for corresponding field and every IllegalArgumentException has different message to print with respect to field.

I am looking for more Generic approach/Refactoring where I can throw IllegalArgumentException only once with a required error message for Invalid condition.

I can think of a situation where I can create variable say errorMeaage and store error message in it, at last, if the variable errorMeaage is not empty 
I can throw IllegalArgumentException with the required message, but this is not convincing me.

Current code :

```
package Miscellanious;

public class ValidationMain {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        ValidationMain obj = new ValidationMain();
        obj.validate("Sam", "Rock", "Turner");
    }

    public void validate(String firstName, String middleName, String lastName) {

        if (firstName != null && !firstName.matches("^[a-zA-Z`’ -]{1,50}$")) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid value for firstName field from Input Parameter");
        }


        if (middleName != null && !middleName.matches("^[a-zA-Z.`’ -]{0,50}$")) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid value for middleName field from Input Parameter");
        }

        if (lastName != null && !lastName.matches("^[a-zA-Z`’ -]{2,50}$")) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid value for lastName field from Input Parameter");
        }

        System.out.println(firstName + " " + middleName + " " + lastName);
    }

}
```

I can Think something like below but it seems it will override the previous error and not much convincing

```
public void validate(String firstName, String middleName, String lastName) {

        String errorMessage = null ;

        if (firstName != null && !firstName.matches("^[a-zA-Z`’ -]{1,50}$")) {
            errorMessage = "Invalid value for firstName field from Input Parameter";
        }


        if (middleName != null && !middleName.matches("^[a-zA-Z.`’ -]{0,50}$")) {
            errorMessage = "Invalid value for middleName field from Input Parameter";
        }

        if (lastName != null && !lastName.matches("^[a-zA-Z`’ -]{2,50}$")) {
            errorMessage = "Invalid value for lastName field from Input Parameter";
        }

        if (errorMessage != null){

            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Error Message :" + errorMessage);
        }

        System.out.println(firstName + " " + middleName + " " + lastName);
    }
```

Comment: don't you think your 'errorMessage' will be overwritten by latest satisfying if clause

Comment: Yes, I have mentioned that. I am aware of the fact.

Comment: ok probably that's what you meant by you not being convinced with it.

Comment: Yes, @Shail016,

Comment: check answer by @ernest_k, below.  That looks like the generic solution to your problem.

Answer (score 2):

One thing you can do is extract the `if` checks to a separate method, which you call with the input, the regex, and the message:

```
private void validateInput(String input, String regex, String message) {
    if (input != null && !input.matches(regex)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Error Message :" + message);
    }
}

public void validate(String firstName, String middleName, String lastName) {
    this.validateInput(firstName, "^[a-zA-Z`’ -]{1,50}$", 
                       "Invalid value for firstName field from Input Parameter");
    this.validateInput(middleName, "^[a-zA-Z.`’ -]{0,50}$", 
                       "Invalid value for middleName field from Input Parameter");
    this.validateInput(lastName, "^[a-zA-Z`’ -]{2,50}$", 
                       "Invalid value for lastName field from Input Parameter");
}
```

Comment: Thanks @ernest_k , this will partially help me, but as mentioned above "there are multiple Fields and Each field has a different set of Validation condition", if there exist new validation condition then I need to change the signature in validateInput and Corresponding all method calls.

Comment: @HargunSuri Have you considered using a validation framework like bean validation?

Comment: unfortunately, I have not used it yet, I will try exploring it.

Comment: It's not that hard to get started, but that may be your best choice. It gives you a way to declaratively set your constraints instead of typing validation logic like this - and you get code written and tested for you :;)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I will surely Check

Answer (score 1):

why not use `else if` to prevent the message from being overridden? this way the code will exit on the first matched condition. This is assuming that you want to stick with your implementation and not edit the code too much.

```
public void validate(String firstName, String middleName, String lastName) {

    String errorMessage = null ;

    if (firstName != null && !firstName.matches("^[a-zA-Z`’ -]{1,50}$")) {
        errorMessage = "Invalid value for firstName field from Input Parameter";
    }else if (middleName != null && !middleName.matches("^[a-zA-Z.`’ -]{0,50}$")) {
        errorMessage = "Invalid value for middleName field from Input Parameter";
    }else if (lastName != null && !lastName.matches("^[a-zA-Z`’ -]{2,50}$")) {
        errorMessage = "Invalid value for lastName field from Input Parameter";
    }

    if (errorMessage != null){

        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Error Message :" + errorMessage);
    }

    System.out.println(firstName + " " + middleName + " " + lastName);
}
```

Comment: It will look very long as I have set of 50 parameters.

Comment: Maybe use something like `javax.validation.constraints.Pattern` you can even specify an error message to be returned with the annotations.

Answer (score 1):

Using your 2nd idea...

```
public void validate(String firstName, String middleName, String lastName) {
        String errorMessage = "Invalid value for fields %s from Input Parameter";
        StringBuffer fields = new StringBuffer();

        if (firstName != null && !firstName.matches("^[a-zA-Z`’ -]{1,50}$")) {
            fields.append("firstName");
        }


        if (middleName != null && !middleName.matches("^[a-zA-Z.`’ -]{0,50}$")) {
            fields.append(" middleName");
        }

        if (lastName != null && !lastName.matches("^[a-zA-Z`’ -]{2,50}$")) {
            fields.append(" lastName");
        }

        if (fields.length() > 0){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Error Message :" + String.format(errorMessage, fields.toString()));
        }

        System.out.println(firstName + " " + middleName + " " + lastName);
    }
```

call with

```
validate("", "1", "");
```

outputs:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error Message :Invalid value for fields firstName middleName lastName from Input Parameter
    at Main.validate(Main.java:26)
    at Main.main(Main.java:5)
exit status 1
```

call with

```
validate("Andres", "1", "Martinez");
```

outputs:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error Message :Invalid value for fields  middleName from Input Parameter
    at Main.validate(Main.java:26)
    at Main.main(Main.java:5)
exit status 1
```